# sed: -e expression #1, char 101: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, yaml

can someone suggest me what is going wrong here -

```bash
sed -i "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS}|g" dep.yaml.
```

The value of CONNECTION_DETAILS is in encoded form:

```
CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX25hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwKICAgICAgICAiZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLAogICAgICAgICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlwdWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg==
```

for:

```
{
    "connection_name_1": "OFSAA_ANALYTICS_PUB",
    "database_name_1": "OFSAA_ANALYTICS_PUB",
    "bi_Services_1":["dv","rpd","bipublisher"]
}
```

Comment: Does `$CONNECTION_DETAILS` contain your `sed` delimiter character, `|` or a newline?

Comment: I don't grok the base64. What is what? Provide complete code (not descriptions of the code: E.g not there was some code before this bit that set CONNECTION_DETAILS  to …).

Comment: @roaima: Yes I'm giving a delimiter as | instead of /

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I have to mount json as value in deployment yaml hence I need to encode and send it as a string otherwise yaml will not accept. The above given json when encoded via base64 format provides the long given string.

Comment: I can see you are giving `sed` the `|` as a delimiter. That's why I'm asking if the variable contains that character or a newline anywhere

Comment: @Meenal, can you provide a complete output of `( set -x; sed -i "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS}|g" dep.yaml )`. Edit it in your question and format it as code so we can understand what you're truly attempting. Edit the `CONNECTION_DETAILS` **prior to** running the command if you feel the need to obfuscate values. Please don't edit them afterwards in the output since that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: What does "encoded form" mean? What, exactly, is in the variable?

Comment: @Meenal, if the variable contains `CSAgewogICAgICA...==` literally, the command should work fine. If it contains something else, why confuse the people you're asking for help from by showing that instead of what it actually contains? Better yet would be to show a complete command that includes the setup and the command that fails.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Yes I agree it works fine when I'm testing this into a separate bash terminal but its failing when its been executed from my shell through pipeline. Although below is the output getting from pipeline, when I did echo ${CONNECTION_DETAILS}-

Comment: CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX25hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwK ICAgICAgICAiZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLAogICAgICAg ICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlwdWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg==

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 101: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @Meenal, executed from your shell _through pipeline_? I don't see a pipeline in the post above. _Show what you're actually doing._

Comment: @Ginnungagap: Here's the output after setting the value of ${CONNECTION_DETAILS},  ( set -x; sed -i "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS}|g" dep.yaml )
+ sed -i 's|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX25hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwK ICAgICAgICAiZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLAogICAgICAg ICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlwdWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg==|g' dep.yaml

Comment: Meenal please stop putting updates in the comments. Use the [edit] button to update your question, and ensure the resulting question makes sense when it's read. Make it easy for people to help you

Comment: @Meenal, I'll just note that the value you posted there in that comment is not the same as the one you posted originally in the question. The one in the comment has whitespace (e.g. at `...wK IC...`), the one in the post doesn't. Now, that whitespace might be newlines, but comments can't be formatted properly, which is one reason why you should [edit] the data in the question instead. These differences matter, the computer doesn't guess what you're meaning to do, and we can't know what you actually have, if you don't show it.

Comment: Break the issue in parts, test them one by one, and then produce a short _but complete_ shell script that shows the issue and that can be copied from the question to run it. And see the part about code formatting in the editing help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CONNECTION_DETAILS` variable contains LF (`\n`) characters.

So, `sed` don't understand the unterminated `s` command. LF before second `"`.

With:

```bash
> CONNECTION_DETAILS='CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX2
5hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwKICAgICAgICAi
ZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLA
ogICAgICAgICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlw
dWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg=='
```

Two solutions:

1. Remove LF chars

```bash
> lf=$'\n'
> echo "xxxxx ##CONNECTION_DETAILS## xxxxx" | sed -e "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$lf}|g"
xxxxx CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX25hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwKICAgICAgICAiZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLAogICAgICAgICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlwdWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg== xxxxx
```

2. Keep LF (escape them)

```bash
> lf=$'\n'
> echo "xxxxx ##CONNECTION_DETAILS## xxxxx" | sed -e "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$lf/\\$lf}|g"
xxxxx CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX2
5hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwKICAgICAgICAi
ZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLA
ogICAgICAgICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlw
dWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg== xxxxx
```

### UPDATE

If you want to add double quotes around the text:

```bash
> lf=$'\n'
> echo "xxxxx ##CONNECTION_DETAILS## xxxxx" | sed -e "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|\"${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$lf/\\$lf}\"|g"
xxxxx "CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX2
5hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwKICAgICAgICAi
ZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLA
ogICAgICAgICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlw
dWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg==" xxxxx
```

Comment: 2nd solution somewhat worked for me as the yaml is replaced with the required value          
            - name: CONNECTION_DETAILS
              value: CSAgewogIC...............................==
            - name: OCPUS
              value: ##OCPUS##
The only thing now I have to do is the string should be enclosed in double quotes. Is there a way I can do this with your suggested sed command i.e. sed -e "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$lf/\\$lf}|g". Thanks much!!

Comment: Use back-double quotes before double quotes: `sed -e "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|\"${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$lf/\\$lf}\"|g"`

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You're using `sed` to manipulate YAML which, while very flexible is likely the wrong tool.

I'd suggest using a more appropriate tool such as [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) for JSON (exclusively) or [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) for JSON/YAML.

`jq` is well established for manipulating JSON, `yq` is a reliable counterpart when you have to manipulate YAML as well.

You don't show much so this is a fairly generic example (using `.config.connection_details` as the value to update) but it could be as simple as:

```bash
$ yq --inplace '.config.connection_details = {"connection_name_1": "OFSAA_ANALYTICS_PUB", "database_name_1": "OFSAA_ANALYTICS_PUB", "bi_Services_1":["dv","rpd","bipublisher"]}' dep.yaml
```

While this works, it looks a lot like `sed` and suffers the same issues regarding characters that can mess with the expression.

As a better alternative, you can feed your value as a separate document which gets injected in the first one:

```bash
$ printf "%s" "${CONNECTION_DETAILS}" | yq eval-all --inplace 'select(fileIndex == 0).config.connection_details = select(fileIndex == 1)' dep.yaml -
```

Since `yq` works with YAML which is a superset of JSON, you can feed it JSON or YAML, it will load it all the same.

Edit: it appears there are multiple `yq`s out there, I'm using Mike Farah's in this answer, there's [a python based one](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) by Andrey Kyslyuk though syntax seems different.

Comment: You should also mention that you are using Mike's `yq` and not Alexey's `yq`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I couldn't find one by Alexey but feel free to edit it in. I already added Andrey Kyslyuk's in case Alexey was a typo.

Comment: Sorry, that's the one I meant. I have too many names in my head.

Comment: The Python one looks better // golang one

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to replace `${CONNECTION_DETAILS}` in your `sed` command with `${CONNECTION_DETAILS//$'\n'}` to remove all line breaks.